# Dynamic textures in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2

I use ROS2/Python/Gazebo Classic project with Galactic.
I am looking for a way to dynamically change textures of objects.
Any ideas how to do it?
I know there is a video plugin, that allows subscribing to images and showing them on FLAT surfaces, but it doesn't work with curved surfaces.
Please help.
Thank you.